# How to convert a Postman request into a NiFi request?

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, postman, apache-nifi, adobe-analytics

*I don't mind if you use an example from another API that is not Adobe Analytics'. I just need to know the pattern that I have to follow in order to succesfully convert a Postman request into a NiFi request.*

After successfully creating requests to pull reports from Adobe Analytics via Postman, I´m having difficulties to migrate these Postman requests to NiFi. I haven´t been able to find concrete use cases that explicity explain how to do this kind of task step-by-step.

I'm trying to build a backend on top of NiFi to handle multiple data extracts from Adobe Analytics in an efficient and robust way. That is instead of having to create all required scripts by myself. Yet, there is more documentation about REST APIs and Postman cases than there is about REST APIs and NiFi cases.

In the screenshot below we can see how the Postman request looks like. It takes 3 headers and 1 temporary header that includes the authorization value (Bearer token). This temporary header is generated automatically after filling in the OAuth 2.0 authorization form in the Authorization tab, as shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lrg1MuVi0Fo).

[image: Postman request]

Then, we have the body of the request. This json text is generated automatically by debugging Adobe Analytics' workspaces as shown [here](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/analytics-learn/tutorials/apis/using-analysis-workspace-to-build-api-2-requests.html).

[image: Body of request]

I'd like to know the following in a step-by-step manner with screenshots if possible:

- Which processor(s) should I use in NiFi to obtain a similar response as the one I got in Postman?
- Which properties should I add/remove from the processor to make this work?
- How should I name these properties?
- Is there a default property whose value/name I should modify?

As you can see, the question mainly refers to properties setup in NiFi, as well as Processor selection. I already tried to configure some processors but I don't seem to get the correct properties setup, or maybe I'm selecting the wrong processors.

I'm using NiFi v1.6.0 and Postman v7.8.0

This is most likely an easy task for users already familiar with NiFi and API requests, but it has proven challenging to me. Hopefully this will help other users looking to build more robust pipelines by using NiFi instead of doing it manually.

Thanks.

Comment: use postman logs to see all requests done to auth your main request, and reprodure all those requests in nifi. https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/debugging_and_logs/

Comment: @daggett I tried doing this and was able to see the raw request. However, I don't know how to accomodate the headers inside a NiFi processor (as properties). Furthermore, I'm not sure which processor should I use. E.g. How to pass the "body" of the request to NiFi.

Comment: Follow documentation: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP/

Comment: This could be useful: http://www.tomaszezula.com/2016/10/30/nifi-and-http-post-configuration/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It only takes 3 NiFi processors to replicate a REST API request that works in Postman. In this solution we use a request that contains a nested JSON request. The advantage of this simple approach is that it reduces the amount of configuration required to obtain a successful response from the API. That is, even if you are using a complex JSON request. In this case the *body* of the JSON request is passed through the `GenerateFlowFile` processor, without the need of any other processor to parse/format the request.

**Step #1.** Create a processor called `GenerateFlowFile`. The only property that you will have to modify is the *Custom Text*. Paste in there your whole JSON request just as it was in Postman. In this case I'm using the very same JSON shown in the question above. It's a good idea to setup *Yield Duration* to 10 seconds or more.

[image: Generate FlowFile]

**Step #2.** Create a processor called `InvokeHTTP`. Then modify the 6 properties shown in the screenshots below. Use the same Authorization details you've used in Postman. Make sure to copy the Bearer token from Postman after it has been tested. Also, don't forget to setup the `HTTP Method`, `Remote URL` and `Content-Type` as well.

[image: InvokeHttp1]
[image: InvokeHttp2]

**Step #3.** Finally, add a couple of `LogAttribute` processors to store the output of `InvokeHTTP`. One of these `LogAttribute` processors should store successful responses. The other one can be used for *Failure, Original, Retry and No-Retry*. Or you can create `LogAttribute` for each of these outputs.

**Step #4.** Now, connect the processors and *Start* your data flow! You should start seeing data populate the *Successful* `LogAttribute`. Then you can use the Data Provenance option to review the incoming data and confirm that this is exactly the same result you previously obtained from Postman.

[image: General data flow]

**Note:** This is a simple, straightforward, "for starters" solution to replicate a Postman API request using a nested static JSON. There are more solutions in StackOverflow that tackle more complex cases, like dynamic JSON. Here's a list of some other posts:

- [nifi invokehttp post complex json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43003890/nifi-invokehttp-post-complex-json)
- [In NiFi processor 'InvokeHTTP' where do you write body of POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53831579/in-nifi-processor-invokehttp-where-do-you-write-body-of-post-request)
- [Configuring HTTP POST request from Nifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39116067/configuring-http-post-request-from-nifi)